# Is the second sentence a correct one? It doesn't have a verb!

Tags: sentence-construction

Another sentence written by my son：

> Why don’t we open up two special areas at our school? **One for PE activities and the other for casual activities.**

The boldface part looks incorrect to me——it doesn't have a verb！Is it a wrong sentence? How to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

> One for PE activities and the other for casual activities.

The sentence is fine. The verbs are there.. sort of. They have been omitted, but they are implied.

> One [of those areas **is**] for PE activities and the other [of those areas **is**] for casual activities.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your sentence like this:

> Why don't we open up two special areas at our school-one for PE activities and the other for casual activities?

Punctuation mark at a proper place can serve our purpose.

Comment: Just a punctuation mark，yeah~. Good!

Comment: CAUTION! you are expressing "school" and "one" as a single Idea which is incorrect. Give a space between the two and put a dash: "School -- one"